# Using method_getReturnType to call specific types of instance member functions

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm new to Objective-C so I don't have much idea about the language.

What I'm trying to do is go through all available instance methods of an object and call the ones that take no arguments, return bool and start with the string "func".

Here's how I get the methods:

```
uint32_t methodCount = 0;
Method * methods = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(self), &methodCount);
```

I iterate through the methods and when the above condition matches, try to call them:

```
NSString * methodName   = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sel_getName(method_getName(method))];

char retTyp[10];
method_getReturnType(method, retTyp, 10);

const char * desiredRetType = "B";

if([methodName hasPrefix:@"func"] &&
   (0 == strncmp(retTyp, desiredRetType, strlen(desiredRetType))) &&
   (2 == method_getNumberOfArguments(method)))
{
     bool * (* testMethod) (id, Method) = (void (*) (id, Method, ...)) method_invoke;
     result = testMethod(self, method);
}
```

I had to experimentally figure out what the return type string is (turns out it's "B" for bool), and the number of arguments.

I'm getting the following error on the line where I'm trying to call the function using method_invoke:

```
cannot initialize a variable of type 'bool *(*)(__strong id, Method)' (aka 'bool *(*)(__strong id, objc_method *)') with an rvalue of type 'void (*)(__strong id, Method, ...)' (aka 'void (*)(__strong id, objc_method *, ...)'): different return type ('bool *' vs 'void')
```

1. Is there a better way to way to do this than class_copyMethodList?
2. How do I cast the function correctly so as to not get an error?
3. Is it possible that the method_getReturnType() conversion of return
   types may change from system to system? Or is it always B for bool?

Comment: Where did `method_invoke` come from?

Comment: On 3, technically yes, but as a practical matter no.

Comment: `method_invoke` came from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1456726-method_invoke?language=objc).

As for 3, could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. The encodings are defined by the compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questionsS/11527385/ but they are also used by the runtime. So they need to be synchronized. You could, therefore, have a compiler/runtime pair that defined them to be _whatever_, but the programs that worked on that pair would be incompatible with any other runtime. So the encodings are sort of _ipso facto_ ABI at this point.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I figured it out. Instead of using method_invoke on the method name, I did this:

```
NSString * methodName   = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sel_getName(method_getName(method))];

char retTyp[10];

method_getReturnType(method, retTyp, 10);
const char * desiredRetType = "B";

if([methodName hasPrefix:@"func"] &&
   (0 == strncmp(retTyp, desiredRetType, strlen(desiredRetType))) &&
   (2 == method_getNumberOfArguments(method)))
{
    SEL testMethod = method_getName(method);
    return [self performSelector:testMethod];
}
```

Comment: This is still wrong. You should be using method_getImplementation(), and cast the result of THAT function pointer to safely invoke the method. `-performSelector:` is U.B. if the signature of the function is not `-(id) func`, which in your case appears to be returning `BOOL`. It will likely work, but may cause issues down the road.